# Extremising a functional with boundary conditions (Euler-Lagrange)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I need to determine all functions $ u(x) $ that extremise the functional: $$ I[u]= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\frac{(u')^2}{2}+(1-\cos u)\right] \, dx $$
subject to the boundary conditions

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} u(x)=0 $$ and $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} u(x) = 2\pi $$
I used the standard approach for finding the stationary points of a functional; that is, attempting to solve the Euler-Lagrange equation, but assuming I've attempted this correctly I arrive at 
$$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \sin u $$
which I believe is not (easily) directly solvable, so I'm presuming there's either another way to approach this problem or I've messed up somewhere. A point in the right direction would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: Note that if you type a\sin b then you see $a\sin b$, with proper spacing to the left and right of $\sin$, and with $\sin$ not italicized, and with a\sin(b) you see $a\sin(b)$, with less space to the right (so the spacing depends on the context) whereas with a sin b you see $a sin b$ with no space before and after $\sin$ even though you typed those spaces there. The same applies to \log, \det, \max, \sup, \lim, etc. With \sup and \lim and some others, this also affects positions of subscripts in some contexts, thus: $$ \sup_{x\in S}\qquad \lim_{x\to0} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{x \to -\infty}\,\mrm{u}\pars{x} = 0\,,\qquad
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\,\mrm{u}\pars{x} = 2\pi\label{1}\tag{1}
> \end{equation}

Multiply both sides of your differential equation
$\ds{\totald[2]{\mrm{u}}{x} = \sin\pars{\mrm{u}}}$ by
$\ds{\totald{\mrm{u}}{x}}$:
\begin{align}
&\totald{\mrm{u}}{x}\,\totald[2]{\mrm{u}}{x} =
\totald{\mrm{u}}{x}\,\sin\pars{\mrm{u}}
\implies
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\totald{\mrm{u}}{x}}^{2} =
-\cos\pars{\mrm{u}} + \mc{E} + 1\ \mbox{where}\
\,\mc{E}\ \mbox{is a}\ constant.
\end{align}

---

Also,
\begin{align}
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\totald{\mrm{u}}{x}}^{2} & =
2\sin^{2}{u \over 2} + \,\mc{E}
\implies
\totald{u}{x} = \pm\root{2\,\mc{E} + 2\sin^{2}\pars{u \over 2}}
\\[5mm] \implies
\pm\int{\dd u \over \root{2\,\mc{E} + 2\sin^{2}\pars{u/2}}} &= x + \,\mc{C}\,,\quad\mc{C}\ \mbox{is a}\ constant.
\end{align}
Note that the integral is related to the [Elliptic Integral $\,\mrm{F}\pars{\phi,k}$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E4). Now, you have to manage to find $\ds{\,\mc{E},\ \mc{C}}$ and the 'suitable' sign $\ds{\pm}$ by using the boundary conditions \eqref{1}.